# How to get milliseconds?

Tags: java, android, datetime-conversion

I'm doing a countdown timer, I got rid of **int** variable and made **long**.
The following methods how I get hours, minutes and seconds.

```
public static long getHours(long totalSeconds) {
    return (long) Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600000);
}

public static long getMinutes(long totalSeconds) {
    return (long) Math.floor((totalSeconds - 3600000 * getHours(totalSeconds)) / 60000);
}

public static long getSeconds(long totalSeconds) {
    return (long) Math.floor(totalSeconds - 3600000 * getHours(totalSeconds) - 60000 * getMinutes(totalSeconds));
}

public static long getMilliseconds(long totalSeconds) {
    return (long) Math.floor(getSeconds(totalSeconds) / 1000);
}
```

For ms I divided the second by 1000. Now I get time in such format
**12:34:56.000**. 
In place of milliseconds are always **.000**

What is wrong?
How to get milliseconds?

Comment: `return totalSeconds * 1000`? And by the way: A method `getSeconds` that retrieves the seconds as an argument and obviously shall return these seconds ... Should that method _calculate_ the seconds?

Comment: if I do return totalSeconds, I get such time 00:00:12.012
etc

Comment: "I get such time 00:00:12.012" In an `int` variable?!? Not possible ...

Comment: milliseconds also int in my code

Comment: use long for miliseconds

Comment: i cannot use long, only int

Comment: long ms = (long) hrs * 60 * 60 * 1000 + min * 60 * 1000; here hrs and min are integer value

Answer (score 1):

"Milli" comes from the Latin language. It means "a thousandth" of something.

Maybe that gives you a hint how you turn a second value into a milli second value.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
public static int getHours(int totalSeconds) {
    return  TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(your seconds);
}
```